# Unremovable 1px padding on container div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to tile a div with spans using flexbox, but however I do it - I always seem to have a 1px top and left padding on the container div and I do not know what might be causing this.

And for some reason it has this gap:

```css
div, span {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 0 !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
    }
    
    div {
      width: 162px;
      height: 162px;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      border: 1px solid gray;
    }
    
    span {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      display: block;
      border: 1px solid gray;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>C</span>
  <span>D</span>
  <span>E</span>
  <span>F</span>
  <span>H</span>
  <span>I</span>
  <span>J</span>
  <span>K</span>
  <span>L</span>
  <span>M</span>
  <span>N</span>
  <span>O</span>
  <span>P</span>
  <span>Q</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see a gap on my end.

Comment: the 1px border is taking away some space. When we remove the border and make the div width as 160px, the extra spacing goes away (the spans fit perfectly in the flex div). I do not know why it behaves this way even after making `box-sizing: border-box`. There might be some inconsistency with flex.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all span tags in one container and use scale there.
It may not be the best solution, but it worked.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transform: scale(1.01);
}
```

```
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <span>A</span>
    <span>B</span>
    <span>C</span>
    <span>D</span>
    <span>E</span>
    <span>F</span>
    <span>H</span>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>J</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, but its hard to believe that a transform hack should be required for such a simple thing :(

Answer (score -1):

You can use table in this case.

```css
table {
  width: 162px;
  height: 162px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

td {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>I</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>J</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>L</td>
    <td>M</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>O</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>Q</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't use tables for purpose layout!

Comment: @Sfili_81 yes, grid is also an alternative.